# Sequential Limit Proofs

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I was reviewing a proof that $\lim(\frac{n+1}{n}) = 1$ and was wondering, what goes wrong if I were to prove that $\lim(\frac{n+1}{n}) = 0$.

Scratch Work:

I try to prove that $\lim(\frac{n+1}{n}) = 0$ (This is obviously false, but it's just a check against my understanding).

$|\frac{n+1}{n} - 0| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |\frac{n+1}{n}| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{n+1}{n} < \epsilon$ (In my opinion, this is valid since $n$ is positive) $\Rightarrow 1 + 1/n < \epsilon \Rightarrow 1/n < \epsilon -1 \Rightarrow n > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$. From here normally, I would say in the proof (when I write it up) that I would choose an $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon - 1}$.

My conjecture is that the proof would fail because the inequality, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ has to hold $\forall \epsilon > 0$. In particular, this choice of $N$ does not work for $\epsilon = 1$. Because my scratch work failed, I cannot write a proof and thus $\lim(\frac{n+1}{n}) \neq 0$

My question is: Is my conjecture correct? If not, what argument would break the "proof" of the false claim.

Comment: In fact you need $\epsilon>1$ in your argument. $\frac 1  n <\epsilon -1$ is impossible if $\epsilon \leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for the response. Due to this restriction of epsilon, does this suffice as an argument for why the proof fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to prove that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, the inequality$$\left|\frac n{n+1}-0\right|<\varepsilon\tag1$$if $n$ is large enough. But, after writing $(1)$, you wrote a sequence of implications, beginning with $\left|\frac n{n+1}-0\right|<\varepsilon\implies\left|\frac n{n+1}\right|<\varepsilon$. That makes no sense: if you want to prove that something is true, the fact that that thing implies another thing is irrelevant.

Actually, most of the time this is not a serious problem here, since most of your implications are actually equivalences, but you should be careful about that. And the assertion $\frac1n<\varepsilon-1\implies n>\frac1{\varepsilon-1}$ is meaningless when $\varepsilon=1$ and false when when $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$.

And simply from the fact that your attempt failed you cannot deduce that there is no proof whatsoever of what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.